# How to make buttons scroll-able in Android, programmatically?

Tags: java, android, button, scrollview

I'm trying to get an arbitrary amount of buttons created on the screen, and then have a way to scroll around the buttons. (up/down)

With a bit of research, I've found that I should be using "scrollview" for what I'm doing. So I've set it up like this..  (full code at http://pastebin.com/05mtszi7)

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Button btnTag = new Button(this);
btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

row.addView(btnTag);

ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
sc.setFillViewport(true);
sc.addView(row);

layout.addView(sc);
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? It's probably something incredibly simple/silly, I know. I've looked all over, but I must really be overlooking something important, here. Everything runs fine, but nothing scrolls.

Thanks in advance, for the help.

Comment: what's your problem you need to clarify...

Comment: @HarshitRathi Nothing scrolls. It's basically static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. this will help you...

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

        TextView menuText = new TextView(this);
        menuText.setText("People");
        menuText.setId(100);
        menuText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(menuText);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


                Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                btnTag.setText( " " + i);
                btnTag.setId(1 + (i));
                row.addView(btnTag);

                btnTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String buttonText = "Unknown Person";
                            Button b = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
                            buttonText = (String) b.getText();

                        TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(100);
                        tx.setText(buttonText + " pressed.");
                    }
                });


            ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
            sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sc.setFillViewport(true);

            sc.addView(row);

            layout.addView(sc);

            setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Thanks,  zohreh's example showed me what I was doing wrong, I basically just added  setContentView(layout); at the end and got what you posted, I think. My final code is here. http://pastebin.com/gRqGhJLn - Thank you to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

you should add buttons to layout then layout add to scrollview.scrollview only can has a child.

```
         LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

                TextView menuText = new TextView(this);
                menuText.setText("People");
                menuText.setId(100);
                menuText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                layout.addView(menuText);

                for (int i = 0; i < users_registered; i++) {

                    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
                    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        btnTag.setText(user_name[i] + " " + i);
                        btnTag.setId(1 + (i));
                        row.addView(btnTag);

                        btnTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String buttonText = "Unknown Person";
                                    Button b = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
                                    buttonText = (String) b.getText();

                                TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(100);
                                tx.setText(buttonText + " pressed.");
                            }
                        });
    layout.addView(row); 
        }//end loop

                    ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
                    sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    sc.setFillViewport(true);

                    sc.addView(layout);

                   // layout.addView(sc);
```

Comment: Is this not what I'm doing?

Comment: edit: Nevermind, I see what you were doing. I fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
    sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    sc.setFillViewport(true);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    row.addView(btnTag);

    layout.addView(row);
    sc.addView(layout);
```

This will help...

Comment: I tried doing it how you said, but the program crashes once it starts up. Any idea as to why?